# Can I call Java process on either GAE or GCE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In my web application, I'm invoking .exe files (java.exe and javac.exe) from within subprocesses by using `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` and `java.lang.Process`:

```
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder builder 
         = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", "someJar" "mainClassName");
```

Can this be done on Google App Engine or do I have to use Google Compute Engine?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's clarify the difference:

- Google App Engine is a PaaS.
- Google Compute Engine is an IaaS.

They are two different things. GAE will give you a full stack out of the box to deploy your web application. GCE will simply give you bare-bone VMs that you have at your disposal to build on top of.

Without fully understanding your question, I think what you want to know is if you will have access to a JVM on both. The answer is yes, you will. With GAE you'll have a JVM out of the box. Depending on which image you use to spin up a GCE instance, you may have to install the JVM yourself on it.

It's important that you understand the difference between them.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/